# Disabling a blogspot/blogger blog after losing access to the owner e-mail account

Tags: blog, blogger

I need to remove a blogspot (AKA Blogger) blog from the Internet. I made it over five years ago, and I no longer have access to the e-mail account that it was created with. As a result, I have no way of closing the blog, deactivating the URL or preventing the blog from being searched.

Apparently Google doesn't remove URLs from its index even if you put them under the category of defamation unless you have a court order.

What can I do to make this blog go away?

Comment: I'm happy to take questions here in the comments, but it could take me a while to respond because I'm not actually the person having the problem. I'm trying to draw in a new user by using the method Jeff Atwood suggested [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/).

Comment: I presume that "you" have forgotten the password too?

Comment: @Barry, I didn't even think to ask about that, but I would imagine so, since this would be a non-issue otherwise.

Comment: Raise a DMCA takedown request?

Answer (score 4):

You - or the person concerned - needs to remember enough details to convince Google that they really did create the blog.

There are links to the forgotten password process (that won't work without access to the email), and to the account recovery exam, here:
http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2010/11/deleting-blogs-and-blog-posts.html

You / they are welcome to take the account recovery exam as many times as you / they wish:  some people report success after the 3rd or 4th attempt.

Remember, the flip-side of this question involves people pretending they made blogs that they didn't really make, and asking to have them taken down just because they don't like what is said.

And if they cannot manage to take the blog down, the other option is to load other stuff on to the internet which will put the undesirable content further down the search-engine result pages.